# sending form data across two pages with added javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck! - I have a search form, that when data is entered and submitted, the data is sent to another page! - this works well see eg below.

My problem is, I have a piece of javascript called "greybox", it basically loads an external, dimming the first page and focusing on the external - see eg below.

[normal working](http://www.nctfleetlist.co.uk/normal.php)

The new window can be called via either a href "rel" link or an "onclick" command.

I have tried implementing the the two together to no success..Whichever method I use, when i use the greybox the data from the original form is not passed over! - this is what I have so far...

example1, Using standard form with an "onclick" function on the submit button [example 1](http://www.nctfleetlist.co.uk/eg1.php)

```
    <body>
    <script>
    GB_show(caption, url, /*optional*/ height, width, callback_fn)
    </script>
    <form name="form1" action="test_script.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="var1" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="return GB_show('Search',                           'http://www.nctfleetlist.co.uk/test_script.php', this.href)">
    </form>
    </body>
```

example 2 - using "onsubmit" [example 2][3]

```
    <body>
     <script>
     GB_show(caption, url, /*optional*/ height, width, callback_fn)
      </script>
      <form name="form1" action="test_script.php" method="post" onSubmit="return     GB_show('Search', 'http://www.nctfleetlist.co.uk/test_script.php', this.href)">
       <input type="text" name="var1" value="">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
       </form>
        </body>
```

example 3 - using a javascript text link

```
    <body>

    <form name="form1" action="test_script.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="var1" value="">
        <a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].submit()" rel="gb_page_center[720, 300]">Search</a>
          </form>

               </body>
```

To see the other working pages, simply change eg1.php to eg2.php or eg3.php

If anyone can help me, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am not clear what you are trying to do here. Do you have two forms in one page and are you trying to submit both at the same time?